# How do I convert a DataFrame from long to wide format, aggregating a column's values by counts

Tags: python, pandas

My setup is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3], 'action':['b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd']})
df

  action  user_id
0      b        1
1      b        1
2      c        1
3      a        2
4      c        3
5      d        3
```

What is the best way to generate a dataframe from this where there is one row for each unique *user_id*, one column for each unique *action* and the column values are the count of each action per user_id?

I've tried

```
df.groupby(['user_id', 'action']).size().unstack('action')

action    a   b   c   d
user_id                
1       NaN   2   1 NaN
2         1 NaN NaN NaN
3       NaN NaN   1   1
```

which comes close, but this seems to make *user_id* the index which is not what I want (I think).  Maybe there's a better way involving `pivot`, `pivot_table` or even `get_dummies`?

Comment: What is the problem with the output you have? It seems fine. Or do you need it transposed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`pd.crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
In [37]: pd.crosstab(index=[df['user_id']], columns=[df['action']])
Out[37]: 
action   a  b  c  d
user_id            
1        0  2  1  0
2        1  0  0  0
3        0  0  1  1
```

Having `user_id` as the index seems appropriate to me, but if you'd like to drop the `user_id`, you could use `reset_index`:

```
In [39]: pd.crosstab(index=[df['user_id']], columns=[df['action']]).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[39]: 
action  a  b  c  d
0       0  2  1  0
1       1  0  0  0
2       0  0  1  1
```